# duplicating columns to enforce constraints?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have some complex constraints required and some span over multiple tables. Is it better to duplicate the column (part of the primary key) to enforce the constraint OR use a stored procedure instead?

Here is an example:

```
create table responses
(
   resp_id int PRIMARY KEY
   participant_id int,
   session_id int,
   form_id int,
   section_id int,
   sec_target_id int,
   quest_id int,
   input_method_id int,
   foreign key(form_id, section_id) references form_sections(form_id, section_id),
   foreign key(section_id, quest_id) references questions(section_id, quest_id),
   foreign key(session_id, form_id) references session_forms(session_id, form_id),
   unique(resp_id, session_id)
);

create table user_responses
(
   resp_id int PRIMARY KEY
   participant_id int,
   session_id int,
   instructor_id int,
   foreign key(resp_id, session_id) references responses(resp_id, session_id),
   foreign key(session_id, instructor_id) references session_instructors(session_id, instructor_id)
);
```

There can be two types of responses: anonymous or user. User responses has an instructor associated with it for each session.
In the table user_responses, I duplicate the column session_id from responses table so I can enforce the constraint that the instructor_id is actually assigned to the selected session.

There are many complex constraints like this and some future additional requirements that may cause a DDL change, is it better to enforce the constraints through a SP or the method above?

Comment: Can a response type be modified?  Can a user_response become anonymous or  an anonymous response get a user?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's generally better to duplicate columns to enforce constraints where this is required.  watch for edge cases where something may change down the road, but in general I see nothing wrong with this approach.  An important point here is that it is helpful to be able to enforce a composite foreign key.  I don't recall if MySQL has this capability but most RDBMSs should.